# Javascript for sticky function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sticky

I'm trying to create a standard sticky-function for my bottom side navigation. It's really just a low functioning tool, making it an absolutely positioned element roughly 300 px from the top of the window to the bottom of the page. It SHOULD be easy. I've written the following code below

CSS

```
.style2info { 
    margin-top:170px;
    height: 3800px;
    background-color: #6B6B6B;
    margin-left: 59px;
    width: 70px;
    position: relative;
}
.anchornav {
    height: 30px;
    width: 25px;
    position: absolute;
}
.anchornav.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var win      = $(window),
    fxel     = $('.anchornav'),
    eloffset = fxel.offset().top;

win.scroll(function() {
    if (win.scrollTop() > eloffset) {
        fxel.addClass("sticky");
    } else {
         fxel.removeClass("sticky");
     }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="style2info"><!-- sticky -->
    <div class="anchornav">
        <p>sticky?</p></div>
</div>
```

On my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/petiteco24601/yjntygaw/), it's working PERFECTLY. The problem is on the actual website, not so much. http://webstage.emich.edu/dining-new/locations.php
(Ignore the inline styles, it's just for as long as I'm still working on the javascript)

The only thing I can think of is that the way it's located on the page, it the larger div ("style2info") has a negative margin-top to position it correctly. Is it possible that that would be messing up my code? Or is it something else?

Any help is always appreciated! Thank you!!!!

******I have read the other stackoverflows regarding sticky objects. the problem is that they're either taking from github, or attempting to do other things. mine is just very straight and simple and I'd like to learn what I'm doing wrong rather than using other programs to do it**

Comment: start from checking console, it should help.

Comment: in location.php your have a html entity `&gt;` instead of using `>` symbol. Instead making a seroate file for the google analytics code. Put the code at the end of your body tag.

Comment: You have to fix any javascript errors on the page - I saw about 3 or 4 errors - they could be preventing the script from executing.

Comment: you misspelled "position" in anchornav's style

Comment: @dowomenfart the server did that when i published the page- is there a way other than an external script sheet to prevent that from happening?

Comment: @MiaSno according to the fiddle, the javascript is "perfectly valid", I appreciate the tip though- but I'm struggling to see the actual errors.

Comment: @CosetteGirardot not the fiddle, your website...

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Thank you @askmatey ,  that would be why I included the properly working fiddle as well as the code that I have on the actual website, because you can see that the "sticky" function is not working on the website, whereas in using the same code on JSFiddle, it is. I included the code in my question, I need to know what about the javascript could be causing complications that are not showing up on JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

So after some careful checking and trying to figure out exactly what was wrong, I found that the serve was just significantly less forgiving than JSfiddle. I reformatted the javascript to the following

```
function sticky_relocate() {
  var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
  var div_top = $('.style2info').offset().top;
  if (window_top > div_top)
    $('.anchornav').addClass('sticky')
  else
    $('.anchornav').removeClass('sticky');
  }
 $(function() {
  $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
  sticky_relocate();
  });
```

Works perfectly now!